# Nestjs cors setup

Tags: nestjs

So I have created a barebones nest project, changing only `main.ts`, following this CORS setup tutorial and I still don't get the desired result:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    cors: {
      origin: ['http://localhost:8000'],
      credentials: true,
    },
  });

  // app.register(helmet);
  app.enableCors({
    origin: ['http://localhost:8000'],
    credentials: true,
  });

  await app.listen(3000);
}

bootstrap();
```

Here is what I get when running the code above (no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header):

[image]

And, for comparison, here is the result when I access my bare bones custom express setup I did a few months ago (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is present):

[image]

=== EDIT

If I update my code like this:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  // app.register(helmet);
  app.enableCors();

  await app.listen(3000);
}

bootstrap();
```

Then I get the following result (`Accesss-Controll-Allow-Origin` is set to `*`, when I want to set it only to `http://localhost:8000`):

[image]

So, **how do I setup CORS with nestjs?**

Comment: Can you check for testing purpose only by removing all the parameters from `enableCors` method and change it to `app.enableCors();` If that works, then we need to check the domain and port from which the requests are made to your server.

Comment: I have tried what you asked for and it indeed works, but doesn't provide the desired results.